# What does FeCl2 mean?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I'm doing a lab for a class , and in the manual, they right the compound as Fe(Cl)$_2$. I looked up that compound, and it has a very high boiling point, but the compound during the lab was already in a liquid state, so I'm pretty confused. Specifically what was created was made from dissolving iron in HCl in a boiling water bath. I don't know much about chemistry, so if you can try to dumb it down, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why does a high boiling point disagree with it being a liquid or dissolved in solution? If the boiling point is high, that means it will likely be a liquid if the temperature is lower than that (or a solid if the temperature is even lower). @user69873

Answer (score 3):

It should be labeled "FeCl2, water solution".  You have a water solution.  Like most metal chlorides, ferrous chloride dissolves readily into water.

Keep it in an airtight container.  Ferrous ion in solution gets oxidized easily.